# How can I use Visual Studio intellisense in MVC .aspx views with Javascript libraries?

Tags: visual-studio, javascript-intellisense

I have a web MVC app that uses jQuery and quite a lot of other Javascript. All in there are over 20 `.js` files that are joined and minified in the production app.

We have a mix of brought in frameworks (like jQuery) and our own Javascript.

So that these files have intellisense we have a common `vsdoc.js` file:

```
/// <reference path="/content/js/frameworks/jquery-..-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="/content/js/frameworks/framework1.js" />
...
/// <reference path="/content/js/frameworks/framework9.js" />
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then at the top of each of our own `.js` files we have:

```
/// <reference path="/content/js/vsdoc.js" />
```

Which means that all of the Javascript we're writing gets intellisense for all of our frameworks.

The problem is in `.aspx` MVC views. We want to get intellisense for all our Javascript when coding in the views, so we have a `vsdoc-page.js` file:

```
/// <reference path="/content/js/vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="/content/js/file1.js" />
...
/// <reference path="/content/js/file9.js" />
```

Then we reference that in the `<head>` of all of our `.master` pages:

```
<% if (false) { %>
    <script src="/content/js/vsdoc-page.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>
```

However that doesn't seem to work at all. Anything we XML document in `vsdoc-page.js` works, but the references within that aren't followed up on.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there some way to get VS to follow the `reference path` in a `.aspx` page in the same way that it does in a `.js` file?

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488208/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-js-in-vs2012/12628049#12628049