# Visual Studio 2012 Intellisense in html files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I am searching a way to have jquery IntelliSense in html files in VS2012.

I followed [this post](http://blog.craigtp.co.uk/post/Javascript-jQuery-Intellisense-in-Visual-Studio-2012.aspx) to setup Intellisense on external js libraries. It works fine for .cshtml, .aspx, .js files but it doesn't work on .html files.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a link to the direct files rather than a references file.  Add the jquery files to the same directory most of the other default files are in and add a reference in that location for the files.

[Intellisense doesn't work for JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488208/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-js-in-vs2012/12628049#12628049)

Also make sure all your intellisense options are checked in general settings and in the javascript intellisense sections of tools - Options