# Knockout region highlighting - visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, knockout.js

Knockout highlighting is not working for me in VS2013.   Given that I have the "knockout highlight color" setting:

[image]

...my assumption is that it should be working.

However, no dice:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? add a `click` event to a `div`?

Comment: Nope.  Just illustrate that highlighting isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. I am a total newbie to Visual Studio, and given that the Web Essentials listed knockoutJS intellisense out of the box I did not think one needed to do anything to 'turn it on'. Also, it seems support for Mustache templating and Angulars ng-bind syntax works out of the box so I was just as perplexed as you.

This is what I did:

I added an entry for a '_refereences.js' file as described in the answer for [Intellisense doesn't work for JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488208/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-js-in-vs2012)

I then created the file, and dragged the knockout.3.0.0.js file into the code area like descirbed on this [blog](http://debugmode.net/2013/11/19/setting-up-visual-studio-2013-for-knockoutjs-development/)

That gave me syntax highlight for Knockout data-binds, as well as Intellisense for Knockout.

Edit: Also check out this [blogpost by Mads Christensen](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs), the man behind Web Essentials. In the blog post he describes what _references.js is for, and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks!   _references.js did the trick!   I did not need to do anything within VS settings - just add the _references.js file to the ~/Scripts/ folder and add the triple slash references to knockout.

Comment: Did the same steps, but with no luck.. :'(