# Make Visual Studio colorize "data-bind" tag

Tags: visual-studio, knockout.js

I'm using knockout, but I would like the Visual Studio editor to colorize the data-bind tag.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874474/knockout-region-highlighting-visual-studio-2013) might help you. 
Also, you can create a new language and specify what keywords it should highlight. 
See this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403324/how-to-create-a-simple-custom-language-colorization-to-vs-code) to create a new language highlighter for **VS Code**.

What I use, I simply do a `ctrl+F` and search for *data-bind* to highlight all the *data-bind*s in the current document. Simple and easy!