# Intellisense doesn't work for JS in VS2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013

Intellisense works for JavaScript but not jQuery.

I have followed these recommendations [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488208/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-js-in-vs2012), but I do not think they work for VS2013 any more.

Since this is my first question, I cannot post images, but my error is identical to the thread linked within this message.  The only difference is that I am using vs2013 professional.

I have placed photos on the MSDN forum so you can see my error [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d9a69e8-38cf-4fe8-9c9f-271d03a19be1/visual-studio-2013-jquery-intellisense-not-fully-working?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: tried to drag the jquery file on top of the Js file where you want to use intellisense :) meanwhile check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488208/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-js-in-vs2012

Comment: Yes sir, I have done that.  I then reset intellisense ctrl + shift + J, and then cleaned and built the solution.  Still no dice.  Is there possibly a vs2013 bug?

Comment: You can report it on connect.microsoft.com but it will take a long time to get response from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your comments that you have this working now, but I'll follow-up with the same response I used on the Microsoft Connect bug reported for this item, in case someone else comes upon this question.

I followed the link to the MSDN forum post at:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d9a69e8-38cf-4fe8-9c9f-271d03a19be1/visual-studio-2013-jquery-intellisense-not-fully-working?forum=wpdevelop

From this post, it looks like the issue is with the JavaScript source:

```
function person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var me = person(brian, 39);
```

When typing "me." you are shown a generic list of identifiers (i.e. names) in the source. This is because the source is not valid JavaScript when executed. First, the person function is being used as a constructor and so you need to use "new person(" to call it. Second, the name brian is used like a variable, but I assume it's supposed to be a string "brian". Here's a corrected version of this source that should fix your issue:

```
function person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var me = new person("brian", 39);
```

I hope this helps!
- Jordan (Microsoft Visual Studio, JavaScript tools team)

Comment: Jordan thanks, I was going to come back and update.  You are correct.  That line hosed the intellisense for me until it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2012 update 4 is more stable then latest 2013 version.

Everything you can do in 2013 can easily done in Visual studio 2012. I have seen many people puzzling a lot for fix the common thing.

Save your time and try VS 12 update 4. You feel it's better stable then 2013.

Hope this help !

Comment: Ok, I will try that in the AM and report back.

Comment: The snippet solution works on VS 2012.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: UPDATE::  JQuery intellisense has started working for me in VS2013.  Some depreciated function such as innerHeight do not, and sometime when you introduce new keywords (ie a function name or variable name, it can get buggy.)  The only thing new I did was create a JavaScript Project.  Then I closed it, and reopened my WP8 solution and jquery intellisence was working.

Answer (score 0):

In VS : go to the "Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScripts >IntelliSense >References"
And add **jquery-version.intellisense.js**  reference  to the list of references and restart visual studio.
it works for me.
Hope this help !