# Knockout js intellisense (autosuggest) not working for Webstorm and Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, knockout.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using knockout js in my simple application. **knockout js works fine in my application**. My problems is why `VS 2013` or `WebStorm` does not show any intellisense for knockout? Also it shows intellisense for `jQuery`.

Currently my codes is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#jqueryTestId").html("Hello world, From jquery.");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: name"/> <br/>
        You've clicked <span data-bind="text: numberOfClicks"></span> times
        <button data-bind="click: incrementClickCounter">Click me</button>

    </div>
    <div id="jqueryTestId">

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
        name : ko.observable(""),
        incrementClickCounter : function() {
            var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
            alert(this.name("TestName"));
            this.numberOfClicks(previousCount + 1);
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In WebStorm it does not show **any** intellisense. But in VS 2013 it only shows `ko` in suggested list, but does not show `observable` function like:

```
ko.observable();
```

How I can enable intellisense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intellisense doesn't work for JS in VS2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232803/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-js-in-vs2013)

Comment: @PWKad i test VS for jQuery but its intellisense works fine

Comment: For WebStorm, your best bet is to configure Knockout as a library like: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html.  From the Libraries dialog, click Download..., then switch the dropdown to "TypeScript community stubs", and pick the Knockout one. This will give you the best intellisense.

Answer (score 8):

You just have to use the debug version of KnockoutJS i did and it autocompleted very well:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.2.0.debug.js"/>
```

[Knockout Debug Version](http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.debug.js)

Hope this Fix your problem :)

Also this works well for "data-bind" tags: [link](http://studgeek.com/2010/08/16/intellijidea-webstorm-knockout-data-bind-attributes/)

Comment: This solved the intellisense issue for RubyMine as well.

Comment: While this indeed solves the issue, I am not 100% happy following the note you can find at knockout official website (check the part in bold):
_Also available: debug build. Note: This is only intended to help you understand how Knockout works. **Don't use it for normal application development, because it exposes additional unsupported private APIs.**_ It would be nice if either knockout is written in a way intellisense is easier or other IDE's adapt to the way knockout declares its code.

Comment: I agree with you as the debug script is also bigger, but if you use it only for the sake of the intellisense autocomplete, I think its fair to change back and forth from the minified to the debug version.

Comment: I think it's possible to keep the debug script out of your main source directory and still get the code completion benefits. I'm not actually using the debug script in any script tag but Webstorm still picks up the library for indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Using knockout.d.ts configured as a javascript library in Settings/libraries/javaScript, as @RP Niemeyer has suggested, is the best solution for WebStorm. Using minified  knockout-3.0.0.js as a library doesn't currently work - see [WEB-10723](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10723)