# javascript not recognized by visual studio 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2013

Yesterday I was working in Visual Studio 2013 on some google map feature using javascript. Today when I started up Visual studio 2013, all my javascript code was in plain black and visual studio wouldn't recognize variables and intellisense didn't work. It's like I'm writing javascript in notepad.. Is this a setting that got changed or just visual studio being silly?

EDIT:
Let me elaborate. I started visual studio this morning and saw that visual studio wasn't interpreting? my javascript code. I had no intellisense support and it wouldn't even pick up a basic javascript keyword such as `var`. I was basically coding blind in sense similar to writing code in notepad(basic text editor). Where is when it worked before, it would highlight all the javascript key words, code-completion, intellisense etc all worked.
Working:
[image]

Not working:
[image]

Comment: To those voting to close this question: It's not off-topic, it's about a tool commonly used for programming. Check the [rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @amphetamachine: Nobody claimed that it's not one of the on-topic technologies. The problem is that it lacks any reproduction steps and is a bit of a vacuous question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then tell the OP how to improve the question in a comment. This isn't an unsalvageable question that's harming the site.

Comment: @amphetamachine: Once again, nobody claimed that it was. You appear to misunderstand close votes. The reason a freshly closed question is actually called "on hold" is that the OP then has an opportunity to improve his or her question. It can then be reopened when fixed.

Comment: The reason why there are no reproduction steps is because there were non. I left my computer, came back the next day and the problem was there(start visual studio, open file) and there it was.

Comment: @john Yes I understand that but the result is still that the question is vague and lacks research. In this case that's not really your fault, it's just how it is. But the result is the same.

Comment: I see what you mean but I've been spending about 2 hours this morning trying to figure out the problem because I had never gotten this before and quite frankly I wasn't sure what could have caused it(reset setting maybe?) . The solution(temporary?permanent?) I found was just by looking around for 2 hours and trying to test different possible origins of the problem. I din't know how to prhase it since I'm not sure if it's to do with the editor itself that's causing the problem or visual studio just being wonky

Comment: I'm not saying you've done anything "wrong", or that you could have tackled the problem better. I'm just saying that this is not a well-fitting question for Stack Overflow. You could have taken it to a forum or chatroom instead, I think. Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: this also happened to me. I just restarted my Visual Studio. Now OK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this a permanent fix but if I right click on the html file and choose `Open With` --> select `HTML(Web Forms) Editor` then everything seems to be working again and my javascript syntax highlighting/intellisense etc works again

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating following packages from Tools> NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console

fire commond `Install-Package jQuery-vsdoc` to update the intellisense for the jquery.

Comment: just tried it, js is still all black. I tried this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488208/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-js-in-vs2012  and my reference groups is set to Implicit(Windows 8), does this have anything to do with the issue perhaps?