# Visual Studio intellisense not working with DHTMLX suite 5

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, dhtmlx

Since I updated my DHTMLX Suite to version 5.0 I don't get intellisense suggestions when typing dhtmlx functions in Visual studio Community 2015 version 14.0.24720.00 update 1.

The functions all work but I have to type them manually and I don't get any feedback on function parameter etc. All non-dhtmlx related functions work as normal with intellisense.

I use my DHTMLX Suite in a MVC project, the dhtmlx.js file is located under `"~/codebase/"` and the View using the js is located under `~/Views/Home/Index`

I use a custom Layout with `<script src="~/codebase/dhtmlx.js")"></script>` in it's header. The View runs the scipts inside `<script type="text/javascript"> functions </script>` tags.

Intellisense did work with DHTMLX Suite 4.6 but not with DHTMLX Suite 5.0. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to be similar to the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488208/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-javascript-in-visual-studio-2012).

Adding the dhtmlx.js as a reference to current group did the trick. To add the reference, select

> Tools > Options

Under

> Text Editor > JavaScript > IntelliSense > References

Find the dhtmlx.js file and write the file path to `Add a reference to current group` and press **Add**.